# Conservation of momentum of ideal gas in pipe

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, ideal-gas, bernoulli-equation

I was reading this question [Pressure drop in a pipe due to cooling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4995/pressure-drop-in-a-pipe-due-to-cooling) and have a follow up question. Please note that the question is about an ideal frictionless pipe.

In the question, it is stated
$$ \rho v = C_1$$
$C_1$ being a constant due to conservation of mass, which makes sense to me, that for every cross section there must be the same mass per second, but then
$$ p+\rho v^2=C_2$$
is stated with the reason being "conservation of momentum". I can't find this equation anywhere else and the reasoning behind it also doesn't make sense to me. If we combine it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle
$$v^2/2 + gz +p/\rho = C_3$$
set $g$ to 0, we can get
$$C_2 - \rho v^2 = \rho C_3 - \rho v^2/2 $$
and
$$C_2 = \rho C_3 + \rho v^2/2 $$
and using the first equation (conservation of mass) we can get
$$\rho C_2 = \rho^2 C_3 + C_1^2/2 $$
which implies that $\rho$ is constant, which seems completely wrong to me.
Momentum is also discussed in the comments and everyone seems fine with using temperature/pressure when talking about conservation of momentum. What doesn't make sense to me is how do temperature/pressure contribute when discussing conservation of momentum. Conservation of momentum is about the **total** momentum, and raising/lowering temperature/pressure, don't affect **total** momentum. If you have a gas in a stationary box the total momentum is zero, and heating or cooling it won't change that.

Where does this equation and reasoning come from?

Comment: Since a gas flowing in a pipe has a relatively low density, I would not think that momentum is not of much concern, especially since friction with the wall of the pipe would cause a loss of momentum. Most of your equations look modifications of Bernoulli's equation which ignores the effect of friction.

Comment: You are correct that in general the momentum of a gas would be low (compared to the pipe), but the question I am following up on was about a frictionless pipe. I didn't add this explicitly to my question, but it's not obvious so I will include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your system is cooling, its energy is not conserved and Bernoulli does not apply. However from 1-d Euler
$$
\rho \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+ v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)= -\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} 
$$
and 1-d mass conservation
$$
\frac {\partial \rho} {\partial t}+ \frac{\partial \rho v}{\partial x}=0
$$
we find the momentum conservation law
$$
\frac{\partial \rho v}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\rho v^2+P\right)=0,
 $$
so in steady flow we have $\rho v^2+P=const$. This is  true  for strictly 1-d flow even if heat energy is being added or lost. It   appears at first to in conflict with Bernoulli (which holds in the flow is isentropic) but in Bernoulli the  speed changes because the pipe changes area, so the Bernoulli flow is not *strictly* 1-d.

In a pipe with a slowly varying area the momentum law becomes
$$
A\frac{\partial \rho v}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial\rho v^2 A}{\partial x}= -A \frac{\partial P }{\partial x}.
 $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This looks like what I was looking for, but I'm not very familiar with the equations. Do you have a link you can share that goes deeper into the first 3 equations you gave?

Comment: You can look at my short note on flow in pipes: http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/deLaval.pdf  They asume isentropic flow when deriving Bernoulli i.e that $dP/\rho=dh$ where $h=U+PV$ per unit mass is the specific entalphy.